# Can I get day details (Sunday - Saturday) through Time Capture API in HMS

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

In Time Awareness I would like to get day information. I there any way to get day details in Time Capture API in HMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Time Capture API will not return Sunday to Saturday information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get these time categories info as integer array from Huawei Awareness Kit via Capture API:

```
TIME_CATEGORY_MORNING = 1;
TIME_CATEGORY_AFTERNOON = 2;
TIME_CATEGORY_EVENING = 3;
TIME_CATEGORY_NIGHT = 4;
TIME_CATEGORY_HOLIDAY = 5;
TIME_CATEGORY_WEEKDAY = 6;
TIME_CATEGORY_WEEKEND = 7;
TIME_CATEGORY_NOT_HOLIDAY = 8;
```

For example, you will get probably this data for Tuesday : [6, 8, 3]